# Do I keep citizen upgrades after starting a new city?

Tags: cityinc

In [CityInc](http://cityinc.se), you can start a new city after getting a certain amount of net value. You can buy citizen upgrades for a certain amount of citizens, like so:

[image: Citizen Upgrades screen]

I was wondering if the citizen upgrades you purchase stay after starting a new city.

Do I keep citizen upgrades after starting a new city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started a new city after buying the parliament upgrade, and the game asks me to buy it again in order to configure it, so yeah:

You do **not** keep the citizen upgrades after starting a new city.